# Why CSpinButtonCtrl is not handling correctly numbers higher than 1000?

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I have a dialog in MFC with a `CSpinButtonCtrl` and an attached buddy (`CEdit`). They work correctly when the maximum value of the spin control is lower than 1000, but if it is higher, the value in the `CEdit` is clamped to the thousand units when the the value is 1000 or higher (it is clamped to 4 instead of 4345, for example).

```
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT IDC_EDIT_1,274,42,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_NUMBER
    CONTROL  "",IDC_SPIN_1,"msctls_updown32",UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,313,42,11,14
END
```

The range is set programmatically:

```
const int max_value = 5000;
auto spin = (CSpinButtonCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_SPIN_1);
spin->SetRange(1, max_value);
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I wasn't able to find any related question to it, I'm publishing my inquiries:

The problem arose from the fact that when the `CSpinButtonCtrl` sets the text of the buddy it converts its numeric value into a string that, by default, includes the thousands separator. As it can be noticed, the `CEdit` control is set to accept only numbers. As the thousands separator is not a number, the `CEdit` clamps the text on it, leaving only the text at the left of the separator (the thousand units in my case).

To solve it, just add the [`UDS_NOTHOUSANDS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) style to the spin control:

```
CONTROL "",IDC_SPIN_1,"msctls_updown32",UDS_NOTHOUSANDS | UDS_SETBUDDYINT | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT | UDS_AUTOBUDDY | UDS_ARROWKEYS,313,42,11,14
```

Of course, another option would be to remove the `ES_NUMBER` from the edit control, but that wasn’t my UI need.